# Reorder axis of heatmap based on non-numeric third variable - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, heatmap

I am creating a heatmap in ggplot2, and I want to reorder the Y-axis.

After looking through past posts I understand how to reorder based on the X- and Y-axes variables, but I want to reorder the Y-axis based on a third, non-plotted, non-numeric variable in my data frame.

My heatmap shows Terms vs Treatments, but each Term has a source database - this is what I want to order the Terms on.
As you can see Terms A and D are from database 2, Term B is from database 1, Term C from database 3.
So the y-axis should be ordered Term B, Term A, Term D, Term C.
It is currently ordered Term D, C, B, A

Edit: This is actually just an extract of my data, I have a lot of terms so would prefer not to have to manually specify the order. I don't have too many databases though, so would be happy to order those manually.

```
library(ggplot2)
terms <- rep(c("Term A", "Term B", "Term C", "Term D"), 3)
treatments <- c(rep("Treatment 1", 4), rep("Treatment 2", 4), rep("Treatment 3", 4))
source <- rep(c("Database 2", "Database 1", "Database 3", "Database 2"), 3)
data <- c(1.923598e-06, 1.307195e-04, 1.307195e-01, 1.307195e-04, 1.740412e-03, 3.446243e-05, 3.834140e-02, 2.654140e-03, 2.976543e-04, 1.111198e-06, 1.376595e-04, 2.923598e-06)
df <- data.frame(terms, treatments, source, data)
ggplot(df, aes(x=treatments, y=terms, fill=-log10(data))) +
  geom_tile()
```

[image: heatmap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution is to add scale_y_discrete and with the limits argument, you can order your y axis with your source variable:

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x=treatments, y=terms, fill=-log10(data))) +
  geom_tile() +scale_y_discrete(limits=unique((df$terms)[order(df$source)]))
```

Comment: This works really well - but my problem is that I actually have ~50 terms so don't really want to order them manually. Sorry, I should have been more clear about that.

Comment: Just edited my answer to fit your large data frame